# Using Phone number to authenticate login instead of UUID in android

Tags: android, uuid

I am trying to use the phone number to authenticate the sign into my app instead of UUID. I haven't found any particular links to look up. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ask user to provide thier phone number. Any other way would be illegal.

Comment: can't you use the ESN?

Comment: Krrishnaaa - I think That is the only way out.
Paul - I want the user to have his details even after he changes his phone like whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way for an Android app to find out the phone number of the device it is running on.

First, not all Android devices are phones.

Second, not all devices have SIM cards that have their correct phone number. Methods like `getLine1Number()` rely on that information.

Here is Google's recommendations on [identifying app installations](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).